# What useful bookmarklets do you use?

Tags: browser, bookmarklet, browser-addons

I use:

- Remove bloat
- [Gmail this](http://email.about.com/library/misc/blgmail_this_bookmarklet.htm)
- [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/help/bookmarklets)
- G-site search
- [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com/#toolbar)
- [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/)

You?

Comment: Delicious will soon be gone. Leaked info from an internal Yahoo  meeting has confirmed this. Be prepared to soon hear about its demise. Start backing up your bookmarks. Meanwhile, the search is on for something as good as or better than delicious. Know any?

Comment: not according to Delicious - http://blog.delicious.com/

Answer (score 25):

The one I probably use the most is [Show Anchors](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2009/12/show-anchors-bookmarklet.html), which I made. It shows an anchor icon next to every element on the page that can be linked to directly.

Sounds stupid, but it's very useful when you want to refer someone to a specific section of a website. And it's much easier than trying to figure out where the site owner put their anchor links (if they even did in the first place).

Comment: I wrote a bookmarklet to solve the same problem by just changing the URL to the closest anchor or ID to the selected text.  This is neat though.. does it show IDs too?

Comment: @intuited: yeah, it does allow you to link to ID's... that's one of the reasons I created my own.

Comment: +1 It is very nice and it would be great if it can even toggle it on and off.

Answer (score 15):

Read Later (marks page for reading later in [InstaPaper](http://www.instapaper.com/extras))

Answer (score 15):

## Kick Ass

http://erkie.github.com

I found this on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). It's fun and likes to get my mind off things and also get rid of them!

Answer (score 12):

[Long URL Please](http://www.longurlplease.com/)

Rewrites most shortened URLs on a page to show where they will take you.

Answer (score 7):

I use [SuperGenPass](http://supergenpass.com/) to hash my master password into unique passwords for the sites I visit (the hash is based on the domain). Very convenient.

Answer (score 6):

[TinEye bookmarklet](http://www.tineye.com/bookmarklet) for finding other sources for images on a webpage.

Answer (score 6):

[BugMeNot](http://www.bugmenot.com/faq.php#05) to quickly bypass the login of web sites that require compulsory registration and/or the collection of personal/demographic information (such as the New York Times).

Answer (score 4):

Quix: http://quixapp.com

This is a little bit like [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28software%29) for the web. It's very useful for web development. You can also [configure Chrome](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/05/27/turn-google-chromes-search-bar-into-a-powerful-quix-command-lin/) to use it as a search engine to turn the address bar into a command line.

Answer (score 4):

I use [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) bookmarklet; it allows to print Stack Exchange questions (like this one) in a printer-friendly way.

```
javascript:(function(){var re = new RegExp('^http://(.*?)\.com/questions/([0-9]+)/');var group = re.exec(window.location.href);if (group!=null){var service = group[1];var questionid=group[2];window.open('http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service='+service+'&question='+questionid)}else{alert('Attention: question id not found!')}})()
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Read Later (sends page to [InstaPaper](http://www.instapaper.com))
2. Clip to [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) (saves
       page as Evernote note)
3. [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/)

Answer (score 3):

I use:

1. [Google Translation Browser Buttons](http://translate.google.com/translate_buttons)
2. [Stack Printer](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)
3. [Bespin Bookmarklet](https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/bookmarklet/)
4. [Bit.ly](http://bit.ly/pages/tools)
5. [Print What You Like](http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/bookmarklet)

Answer (score 3):

[jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) is the bookmarklet I can not live without. Adds (if necessary) jQuery to the list of scripts on the page. Makes writing other little bookmarklets much less painful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my own bookmarklet for all Stack Exchange sites:

This code will show your upvote count for all tags that appear in your user page's top tags section. It should work on any Stack Exchange site you are logged in on (but I've only tested it on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow). Unfortunately there is a [bug in the tag synonym redirection logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66679/bug-in-synonym-top-users-link) that will keep this script from working with tag synonyms.

```
javascript:var uP=$('#hlinks-user a:eq(1)')[0].href;var uN=uP.replace(/.*\//gi,'');var uI=uP.replace(/.*\/([\d]+)\/.*/,'$1');var tsp='/tags/$0/topusers';var tqp='/questions/tagged/$0';var rD='result';var mA=5;var cA=0;var cO=0;var tT;var aT=[];var rT=[];var lI=function(tA,tP,tX,tT,bK){return' <span style="font-size:smaller;">[<a style="color:#777" href="'+tP.replace('$0',tA)+'"'+(bK?' target="_BLANK"':'')+(tT?' title="'+tT+'"':'')+'>'+tX+'</a>]</span>';};var pR=function(){if($('#'+rD).size()==0){$(document.body).append($('<div id="'+rD+'"></div>').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0','bottom':'0','left':'0','width':'40ex','background':'#fff','border-right':'solid #777 5px','overflow':'auto','text-align':'left','padding':'.3em'}));}};var dR=function(){rT.sort(function(a,b){return b[1]-a[1];});$('#'+rD+' h3').html('Your top '+tT+' tag scores:');$.each(rT,function(index,item){var tA=item[0],sC=item[1];var select=$('#tA'+(index+1));select.find('td:eq(1)').html(tA+lI(tA,tqp,'q','questions')+lI(tA,tsp,'s','stats'));select.find('td:eq(2)').html(sC);if(sC>99){select.find('td:eq(2)').css({'background':(sC>999?'gold':sC>399?'silver':'#A67D3D')});} select.find('td:eq(0)').remove();select.find('td').css({'padding':'.3em'});});};var dP=function(){if(aT.length==0&&cA==0){dR();return;}else if(cA<mA&&aT.length>0){rS(aT.pop());} window.setTimeout(dP,200);};var rS=function(tA){cA++;var oS=++cO;var dI='tA'+oS;$('#'+rD+' table').append($('<tr id="'+dI+'"><td>'+oS+' / '+tT+'</td><td>'+tA+'</td><td>...</td></tr>'));jQuery.get(tsp.replace('$0',tA),function(data){var sT=$(data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,'')).find(".fl:eq(1) a[href*='"+uI+"']").parents('tr:eq(0)').find('.top-count:eq(0)').contents().text().trim().replace(/\D+/,'');rT.push([tA,sT?parseInt(sT):0]);$('#'+dI+' td:last').html('Done.');cA--;});};var tU=function(){jQuery.get(uP,function(result){fT($(result.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,'')));})};var fT=function(pN){if(!pN)pN=$('html');pN.find('.user-stats-table:eq(3) a.post-tag').each(function(index,item){aT.push(item.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi,''));});tT=aT.length;$('#'+rD).html('<h3>Retrieving tag scores...</h3><table style="width: 100%;"></table>');dP();};pR();if(document.URL==uP) fT(false);else tU();void(0)
```

And here is a readable non-bookmarklet version of the script:

```
// begin config
var uP = $('#hlinks-user a:eq(1)')[0].href; // user page URL
var uN = uP.replace ( /.*\//gi, '' ); // user name
var uI = uP.replace(/.*\/([\d]+)\/.*/, '$1'); // user id
var tsp = '/tags/$0/topusers'; // template for stats page
var tqp = '/questions/tagged/$0'; // template for questions page
var rD = 'result'; // dom id for generated div
var mA = 5; // max concurrent ajax requests
// end config

var cA = 0;  // current ajax requests
var cO = 0;  // current tag offset
var tT;      // total number of tags
var aT = []; // all remaining tags
var rT = []; // retrieved tags (format: [[tag,score]]
var lI = function(tA,tP,tX,tT,bK){ // build link using a tag, a template and a text
    bK = bK!==false;
    return ' <span style="font-size:smaller;">[<a style="color:#777" href="'
           + tP.replace('$0', tA) + '"'
           + (bK ? ' target="_BLANK"' : '')
           + (tT ? ' title="' + tT + '"' : '')
           + '>' + tX + '</a>]</span>';
};
var pR = function(){ // prepare result div
    if($('#'+rD).size()==0){
        $(document.body).append(
            $('<div id="' + rD + '"></div>')
                .css({
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'top':'0',
                    'bottom':'0',
                    'left':'0',
                    'width':'40ex',
                    'background':'#fff',
                    'border-right':'solid #777 5px',
                    'overflow':'auto',
                    'text-align':'left',
                    'padding':'.3em'
                })
        );
    }
};
var dR = function(){ // display results
    rT.sort(function(a,b){
        return b[1]-a[1];
    });
    $('#'+rD+ ' h3').html('Your top '+tT + ' tag scores:');
    $.each(
            rT,
            function(index, item) {
                var tA = item[0], sC = item[1];
                var select = $('#tA'+(index+1));
                select.find('td:eq(1)').html(tA + lI(tA,tqp,'q','questions') + lI(tA,tsp,'s','stats'));
                select.find('td:eq(2)').html(sC);
                if(sC > 99){
                    select.find('td:eq(2)').css({
                        'background' : (
                            sC > 999 ? 'gold'   :
                               sC > 399 ? 'silver' :
                               '#A67D3D'
                        )
                    });
                }
                select.find('td:eq(0)').remove();
                select.find('td').css({'padding':'.3em'});
            }
        );

};
var dP = function(){ // dispatcher function
    if(aT.length == 0 && cA == 0){
        dR();
        return;
    }else if(cA < mA && aT.length > 0){
        rS(aT.pop());
    }
    window.setTimeout(dP, 200);
};
var rS = function(tA){ // retrieve tag score
    cA++;
    var oS = ++cO; // current offset
    var dI = 'tA' + oS; // corresponding dom ID
    $('#'+rD + ' table').append($(
        '<tr id="' + dI + '"><td>'+oS+' / ' + tT + '</td><td>'
        + tA + '</td><td>...</td></tr>'
    ));
    jQuery.get(tsp.replace('$0', tA),function(data){
        // score as text:
        var sT = $(data.replace( /<img[^>]*>/gi, ''))
        .find(".fl:eq(1) a[href*='" + uI + "']")
        .parents('tr:eq(0)').find('.top-count:eq(0)')
        .contents().text().trim().replace(/\D+/,'');

        rT.push(
            [tA,sT ? parseInt(sT) : 0]
        );
        $('#' + dI + ' td:last').html('Done.');
        cA--;
    });
};
var tU = function(){ // get user page via ajax
    jQuery.get(uP, function(result){
        fT($(result.replace( /<img[^>]*>/gi, '')));
    })
};
var fT = function(pN){ // find tags in page node
    if(!pN)pN = $('html');
    pN.find('.user-stats-table:eq(3) a.post-tag').each(
        function(index,item){
            aT.push(item.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, ''));
        }
    );
    tT=aT.length;
    $('#'+rD).html('<h3>Retrieving tag scores...</h3>'
        + '<table style="width: 100%;"></table>');
    dP();
};
pR();
if(document.URL==uP)// we're in user page
    fT(false);
else // load user page per AJAX
    tU();
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a couple of bookmarklets (named + and -) to quickly increment or decrement the page of an article I'm reading.

Decrement:

```
javascript:(function()%7B%20var%20e,s;%20IB=-1;%20function%20isDigit(c)%20%7B%20return%20(%220%22%20%3C=%20c%20&&%20c%20%3C=%20%229%22)%20%7D%20L%20=%20location.href;%20LL%20=%20L.length;%20for%20(e=LL-1;%20e%3E=0;%20--e)%20if%20(isDigit(L.charAt(e)))%20%7B%20for(s=e-1;%20s%3E=0;%20--s)%20if%20(!isDigit(L.charAt(s)))%20break;%20break;%20%7D%20++s;%20if%20(e%3C0)%20return;%20oldNum%20=%20L.substring(s,e+1);%20newNum%20=%20%22%22%20+%20(parseInt(oldNum,10)%20+%20IB);%20while%20(newNum.length%20%3C%20oldNum.length)%20newNum%20=%20%220%22%20+%20newNum;%20location.href%20=%20L.substring(0,s)%20+%20newNum%20+%20L.slice(e+1);%20%7D)();
```

Increment:

```
javascript:(function()%7B%20var%20e,s;%20IB=1;%20function%20isDigit(c)%20%7B%20return%20(%220%22%20%3C=%20c%20&&%20c%20%3C=%20%229%22)%20%7D%20L%20=%20location.href;%20LL%20=%20L.length;%20for%20(e=LL-1;%20e%3E=0;%20--e)%20if%20(isDigit(L.charAt(e)))%20%7B%20for(s=e-1;%20s%3E=0;%20--s)%20if%20(!isDigit(L.charAt(s)))%20break;%20break;%20%7D%20++s;%20if%20(e%3C0)%20return;%20oldNum%20=%20L.substring(s,e+1);%20newNum%20=%20%22%22%20+%20(parseInt(oldNum,10)%20+%20IB);%20while%20(newNum.length%20%3C%20oldNum.length)%20newNum%20=%20%220%22%20+%20newNum;%20location.href%20=%20L.substring(0,s)%20+%20newNum%20+%20L.slice(e+1);%20%7D)();
```

Answer (score 2):

[PrintLiminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) - Similar to other printing bookmarklets, but lets you select elements to remove from the page.

Answer (score 2):

[Remember password](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html#remember_password) to remove autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 1):

[Coralize](http://www.coralcdn.org/plugins/) for adding a site to the [Coral CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coral_Content_Distribution_Network) before it gets [slashdotted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect).

Similarly:

[Google Cache](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/07/useful-google-bookmarklets.html)

[Way Back Machine/Internet Archive](http://www.gyford.com/misc/wayback.html)

Answer (score 1):

KeepVid: http://keepvid.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have a large screen. Some websites don't limit the maximum width of the content. That often makes long texts unreadable. So my favorite bookmarklet is this. It **limits the maximum width** of the page.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20newSS,%20styles='body%20{max-width:%20800px;}';%20if(document.createStyleSheet)%20{document.createStyleSheet(%22javascript:'%22+styles+%22'%22);}%20else%20{newSS=document.createElement('link');%20newSS.rel='stylesheet';%20newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);%20document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(newSS);}})();
```

Comment: Why don't you use `document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].style.maxWidth = '800px';`? Seems to me far easier than adding a new style sheet..

Answer (score 1):

[XRAY](http://westciv.com/xray/)
I use it to see the box model for any element on any web page.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who likes bookmarklets should have a look at the [iMacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Social_Scripting) Firefox and chrome extensions. They let you create "macros" (kind of like huuge bookmarklets) to autoamte task. We use them for all kinds of "stuff" in the office.

Creating iMacros "Bookmarklets" in Firefox:
[image: Creating iMacros "Bookmarklets"]

Answer (score 1):

Aardvark, which is both a Firefox extension and a bookmarklet (for Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer).  It is useful for web developers as well as people who just want to clean up a page prior to printing it.   http://karmatics.com/aardvark/

Answer (score 1):

Eventually [Zap Colors](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html) gets installed on any browser I use. Gray text on a black background? Zap and it's suddenly readable.

Answer (score 1):

I have my own collection of such utilities those can be found here...

http://saraswaticlasses.net/sites/links4.php

Answer (score 1):

I use [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/) and the diigolet on safari, they have a [toolbar](http://www.diigo.com/tools/toolbar) for some browsers though.

Trust me, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia Search](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/~axel/bookmarklet.html) for searching the highlighted text on Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon universal wishlist](http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/get-button) for tracking things I might want to buy later (birthdays, Christmas gifts, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of useful [bookmarklets for Google services](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/07/useful-google-bookmarklets.html):

- Subscribe in Reader
- Translate
- Bookmark in Google Bookmarks
- Add Event
- Map this
- Google Cache
- Definitions

Answer (score 0):

I use the following bookmarklets:

- [Share on Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/goodies)
- [ReclaimPrivacy](http://www.reclaimprivacy.org/) (This checks how much *accessible* you are in Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a web designer, or someone who loves typography, you'd enjoy [Font Friend](http://somadesign.ca/projects/fontfriend/) bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void(eval("window.document.onmouseup=null;window.document.onmousedown=null;window.document.onmouseover=null;window.document.onmouseout=null;window.document.oncontextmenu=null;"))
```

It prevents the page from capturing mouse events in JavaScript, useful for sites that won't let you right-click or select text. I am not sure where it's originally from, though.

Answer (score 0):

A couple for the Twitter web interface:

- [DeClutter Twitter](http://www.conroyp.com/2010/03/11/declutter/): Filters out all tweets which match pre-defined keywords (iPad, 4square, etc)
- [Hovercard Removal](http://www.conroyp.com/2010/03/20/decluttering-twitter-part-deux/): Stop hovercards from automatically appearing and blocking a whole tweet whenever you mouse over a username

Both of these are quick bookmarklets I threw together to scratch an itch, and use most days. Keyword filtering in particular is something that is supported in several twitter clients but still hasn't made it to the web interface yet, so that bookmarklet makes my timeline much more readable on Apple product launch days / during sport games I'm not interested in / etc!

Couple of simple non-twitter ones based on the url of the site you're on:

- When a site you're visiting is down, check [DownForEveryOneOrJustMe.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com) to quickly see if it's a network issue your side or not
  `javascript:window.location%20=%20'http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/'+window.location.host;`
- Probably pretty niche, but do a [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) lookup on the current domain:
  `javascript:window.location%20=%20'http://who.is/whois/'+window.location.host;`

Answer (score 0):

[Kippt](http://www.kippt.com/) for saving URLs I also want to access from my mobile devices.

[Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/) for making article more readable for my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug, but in addition to the [Amazon Wishlist](http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/get-button) bookmarklet I use the [Woot This Deal Button](http://deals.woot.com/deals/bookmarklet) when I find a good deal for a product online that I want to buy.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh, I can't believe no one has mentioned a JavaScript shell:

https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html

Answer (score 0):

[PageZipper](http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/pagezipper) loads multi-page articles onto one page.

Answer (score 0):

I use this from time to time:

```
javascript:b=document.body;b.contentEditable=b.contentEditable=='true'?'false':'true';void(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, from the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/favelets.html), very handy for web developers:

```
javascript:window.open('http://validator.w3.org/check?uri='+escape(window.location));void%200
```

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) to show all attached event handlers

Answer (score 0):

[WTF](http://nouincolor.com/wtframework/2.0/) - to determine what JavaScript libraries are in use on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I use view source on Internet Explorer 
It lets me see the real dom (including all javascript manipulations) of the current page

```
javascript:(function(){c=unescape(document.documentElement.innerHTML);c=c.replace(/&/g,'&');c=c.replace(/</g,'<');c=c.replace(/>/g,'>');c=c.replace(/</g,'&lt;');c=c.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');document.write('<html><head><title>Source%20of%20Page<\/title><\/head><body><pre>'+c+'<\/pre><\/body><\/html>');x.document.close();})();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one : "View Cookies"

```
javascript:alert('Cookies%20stored%20by%20this%20host%20or%20domain:\n\n'%20+%20document.cookie.replace(/;%20/g,'\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal Wishlist - [Whimventory](http://www.whimventory.com)

Answer (score 0):

While [Opera has an option to automatically reload a web page at pre-defined intervals](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2006/03/reload-page-every-n-minutes.html), Internet Explorer, Firefox & Safari do not have any such feature by default.

Here's my version of a [bookmarklet to automatically refresh any web-page after a specified interval](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-continuously-refresh-any-web.html). This is useful for tracking web-pages that serve info dynamically but may not have implemented AJAX to auto-refresh.